# Iteration over hash, with array as key

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -wKU

h = {}
h[[1, "a"]] = "first"
h[[2, "b"]] = "second"

puts h.to_yaml

# case 1 - works fine
h.each do |k, v|
  num, char = k
  puts "key = #{[num, char]}; value = #{v}"
end

# case 2 - works fine
h.each_key do | num, char |
  puts "key = #{[num, char]}; value = #{h[[num, char]]}"
end

# case 3 - Doesn't work
# how can I get all three values in one go?
h.each do | [num, char], v |
  puts "key = #{[num, char]}; value = #{v}"
end
```

How would I create an iterator where I could get all 3 values (key[0], key[1], value) assigned in the block parameters? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
h.each do | (num, char), v |
  puts "key = #{[num, char]}; value = #{v}"
end
```

Comment: This is a really nice feature, and works with anything that defines `#to_ary`!